# MySQL error #167 - Out of range value for column even when it is autoincremented

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, auto-increment

I have a field (called ID) that is defined as:

```
smallint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=32768
```

I have a query as follows (simplified):

```
INSERT INTO delivery (`ConsigneeName`, `ConsigneePhone`) VALUES ('John Doe', '9999999999')
```

And have also tried

```
INSERT INTO delivery (`ID`, `ConsigneeName`, `ConsigneePhone`) VALUES (NULL, 'John Doe', '9999999999')
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
#167 - Out of range value for column 'ID' at row 1
```

So what could be the problem?  I am at my wits end - have tried with ' and ` on the field names and on the values just to see if that was the problem, but I get the same result.  I even tried the phpmyadmin interface to insert values (and left ID blank) but I get the same error.

Thanx in advance for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your autoincrement starts outside of the range of  smallint datetype. So you can not add any entry. 
Change the datatype of this column to int.

See [the mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) about datatype ranges

> SMALLINT -32768 32767

Comment: Why does the autoincrement start outside the range?  I am not giving it any value at all.  So it should create a valid value.

Comment: @Chiwda you give: `AUTO_INCREMENT=32768`

Comment: That's in the definition of the field.  I'm NOT GIVING ANY VALUE.  Also, the table is empty, right now at least, so it should start with 1.

Comment: @Chiwda THAT IS THE START VALUE and Autoincrement tries to add one to it

Comment: I the table already inserted full and somebody delete data by DELETE query. if you want reset  auto increment value use TRUNCATE TABLE query or ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Comment: `I'm NOT GIVING ANY VALUE` - and he doesn't even read what his create table statement says. +1 from me, this is the correct answer. @Chiwda you should pay attention to what you do before you start caps lock-ing on people.

Comment: That's not from my create statement.  I had created the table a while ago and I did an export to get those values.  I have not ever set the values of AutoIncrement.  Sorry, about the CAPS LOCK if it appears offensive, but I keep coming back to the point that I have not provided any value to the AutoIncrement or to the field itself.  So that will maybe remain a mystery.  I did add 10 records using import from CSV (and they numbered 1 to 10) and then deleted them, but that's about it.  I just now TRUNCATED the table as suggested and it now works.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that one of the failed INSERT statements while I was experimenting set that value.

Comment: @Chiwda So someone has entered the max number of entries, thats why the Auto_increment Counter is at the end

Comment: @Chiwda BTW: If you delete a record, the AUTO_INCREMENT Counter will not set back